# How do you edit torrc file while in TAILS?

Tags: configuration, tails

I have been running TAILs with the TOR browser already installed in the system. When trying to access "torrc" file which is located in etc/tor it constantly refuses to allow it to be edited with text editor within TAILs.

Looking over the net for answers I have tried
A. Setting up Admin Password at the beginning
B. Tried using sudo [command] to see if it raises privelege
C. Copy the file to persistent volume. No luck

The constat roadblock/message that comes up is "You do not have the permissions necessary to open the file". Tried to look at file properties, all access is grayed out. The group says "Debian-Tor".

I want to exclude specific nodes and was able to do it installing TOR on windows but TAILs is not letting any access to that file. Need help to know how to edit the "Torrc" file.

Answer (score 0):

> Looking over the net for answers I have tried A. Setting up Admin Password at the beginning B. Tried using sudo [command] to see if it raises privelege

This should work fine, but there's an additional step, restart tor.

1. Edit the torrc. Don't forget to save the changes with CTRL+x

> sudo nano /etc/tor/torrc

2. Restart tor service to use the modified torrc:

> sudo systemctl restart tor